# Is it correct to use past perfect continuous with "during"?

Tags: sentence-construction, tense

> As soon as I realised the big box placed outside of my room, which had been making you feel inconvenient to go along the corridor during the past 3 days, now I would like to say sincerely sorry to you.

The period of the inconvenient time was happened 3 days ago till the time that I realised the problem. So is it grammatically correct to use the tense of past perfect continuous with the word "during" in this example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be possible, but other problems with the sentence make it difficult to be sure. *As soon as I realised . . .* has normally to be followed by a main clause containing a verb in the past tense. It cannot be followed by the modal *would*. The whole sentence really needs recasting. The way you put it depends your relationship with your neighbour, but if the relationship is a formal one, you might want to say something like:

> I’m very sorry if the large box outside my room has caused you any
>   inconvenience over the past three days. I realise it must have made it
>   difficult for you to get down the corridor, [*if appropriate*: but
>   you’ll be pleased to know that I have now removed it.]

Comment: You could also say "As soon as she gets here we're ready to go." In the sentence used by the OP, the verb is using the past tense, and I would expect the other verb to use the past tense too. "As soon as I realized she lied, she will move to another town." would be wrong, to my ears.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to start the sentence with *as soon as*, you should rephrase it as follows, for example:

> As soon as I realized the big box placed outside of my room caused you any inconvenience, I removed it. Now I would like to sincerely say I am sorry.

*Realize* is used as "I realized I was rude." In your sentence, taking off the parenthetical, you said "I realized the big box placed outside of my room"; it misses a verb. You should remove the comma and *which*, to obtain "As soon as I realised the big box placed outside of my room had been making you feel inconvenient to go along the corridor during the past 3 days." It is too verbose; "caused you any inconvenience" is a shorter way to say what you are trying to say.
"As soon as" is used as "As soon as she arrives we are ready to go." Your sentence is missing a clause. What did you do when you realized the box caused her/him any inconvenience?
You cannot use a comma before "now I would like to say sincerely sorry" since that is a new sentence.